# How can I get all the photos in my phone' s gallery

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I thought I can use photo library plugin but I think that is not maintained(it keep saying there is no permission)

any alternative way that I can get all images from my device?

I know there is camera plugin to get my picture but it always open popup ui then let users select picture. I hope I can get all images without selecting image.

code :

```
import { PhotoLibrary } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/photo-library/ngx';

      this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization({read:true,write:true}).then(() => {
        this.photoLibrary.getLibrary().subscribe({
          next: library => {
            library.forEach(function(libraryItem) {
              console.log(libraryItem.id);          // ID of the photo
              console.log(libraryItem.photoURL);    // Cross-platform access to photo
              console.log(libraryItem.thumbnailURL);// Cross-platform access to thumbnail
              console.log(libraryItem.fileName);
              console.log(libraryItem.width);
              console.log(libraryItem.height);
              console.log(libraryItem.creationDate);
              console.log(libraryItem.latitude);
              console.log(libraryItem.longitude);
              console.log(libraryItem.albumIds);    // array of ids of appropriate AlbumItem, only of includeAlbumsData was used
            });
          },
          error: err => { console.log('could not get photos'); },
          complete: () => { console.log('done getting photos'); }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('permissions weren\'t granted'));
```

ionic info

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/Users/pedrojung/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.3.6
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.9
   @angular/cli                  : 14.2.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 11.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.7.1

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.11.4
   NodeJS            : v14.17.3 (/Users/pedrojung/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.13
   OS                : macOS Ventura
   Xcode             : Xcode 14.1 Build version 14B47b
```

Comment: That plugin doesn't work anymore

Comment: yes, I wonder if there is a alternative one...maybe I should change to flutter :(